# Remove List Item using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `div` that contains an un-ordered list. The list can have any number of list items.

The div's height is `200px`.

I want to remove extra list items that exceed more than `200px`.

```
<div style="height:200px;">
<ul>
 <li>value1</li>
 <li>value2</li>
 <li>value3</li>
 <li>value4</li>
 <li>value5</li>
 <li>value6</li>
 ...
 ...
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use overflow attribute. Put "overflow:hidden" in the style attribute of the div. It will hide everything what exceed div height and width.

Comment: @Tamara : Is setting the overflow attribute same as removing the element ?

Comment: Suggestion : Instead of removing add scroll http://jsfiddle.net/xabUj/

Comment: @user: Please clarify. Do you actually need them removed entirely from the DOM, or do you just want them to be not seen?

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/xabUj/3/

```
$(function () {
    if ($('ul').height() > 200) 
        for(var i = $('ul li').length;i>0;i--)
            if($('ul').height() > 200)
                $('ul li').eq(i).remove();
            else break;

});
```

Comment: Are you sure this will remove the elements at the bottom of the list?

Comment: I'm sure not, i think i don't understood question here

Comment: @roasted: Am I missing anything http://jsfiddle.net/xabUj/1/ ?

Comment: @roasted you need to test the height of the `ul` I think

Comment: Well the questions states that if the items exceed 200px they should be removed - at first glance it looks like your proposed solutions would start removing them from the top of the list.

Comment: I'll post a workaround

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this:

```
while($("ul").height() > 200)
{
    $("ul").remove($("ul li:last-child"));
}
```

EDIT:

Make sure the overflow on your list is set to auto otherwise it might not report the correct height.

e.g. in css:

```
ul {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: No worries, check the edit or you might run into strife.

Comment: @user2504994 This is the best solution if you really want to remove LIs (otherwise use overflow:hidden)  But code should be: `$("ul li:last-child").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
$("ul li").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    counter += $this.height();
    if(counter > 200) $this.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qr5HB/)**

Just add `overflow: hidden` to your `div` element, It won't remove your elements really, but it will hide them.

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $div = $('div'), $ul = $div.find('ul');

$.each($ul.find('li').get().reverse(), function(){
    if($ul.outerHeight(true) > $div.innerHeight()){
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AjqU9/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/AjqU9/3/

```
 <div style="height: 200px;position:absolute;">
        <ul>
            <li id="Li1">value1</li>
            <li id="Li2">value1</li>
            <li id="Li3">value1</li>
            <li id="Li4">value1</li>
            <li id="Li5">value1</li>
            <li id="Li6">value1</li>
            <li id="Li7">value1</li>
            <li id="Li8">value1</li>
            <li id="Li9">value1</li>
            <li id="Li10">value1</li>
            <li id="Li11">value1</li>
            <li id="Li12">value1</li>
            <li id="Li13">value1</li>
            <li id="Li14">value1</li>
            <li id="Li15">value1</li>
            <li id="Li16">value1</li>
            <li id="Li17">value1</li>
            <li id="Li18">value1</li>
            <li id="Li19">value1</li>
            <li id="Li20">value1</li>
            <li id="Li21">value1</li>
            <li id="Li22">value1</li>
            <li id="Li23">value1</li>
            <li id="Li24">value1</li>
            <li id="Li25">value1</li>
            <li id="Li26">value1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div li').each(function () {
        var thi_li = $(this);

        if (thi_li.position().top >= 200)//li that after 200px heigth
        { thi_li.remove(); }
    })
</script>
```